# Using PHP/JS to perform actions

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

to help teach myself PHP I've tasked myself with updating old mysql_* code with PDO.

This has been going great, and as I've been learning I've been able to greatly reduce the amount of code. However my research has ran into a brick wall in a particular area.

Currently, we have it so projects are recorded in a list view, with a set of 'actions/options' for each project. Each of these actions links to a PHP file which runs a small amount of code then sends you back to the list view.

Here is an example:

```
function projectComplete(id) {
    location.href = "complete.php?id=" + id;
}

<button type="button" class="projectComplete" onclick="projectComplete('<?= htmlentities($row['projectid']); ?>')"></button>
```

The complete.php file simply contains an SQL update query that sets a column in the record a completed state of '1'.

I originally wanted to ask the question 'what is the best practice for handling this type of interaction' however that may attract opinion based answers which I read is not allowed here.

Instead I will phrase it like this: Is there a way of having all of these 'actions' run in the same page? (ideally able to use buttons rather than forms, due to difficulty in layout styling of forms)

I know that if it used forms, I could simply name each form's submit button differently then run an if statement (the only issue would be passing the id, but I'm sure I could figure that out e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['exampleAction'])) { Run the code.. }
```

Any links to guides/tutorials/similar questions etc would be very much appreciated. As previously stated, I'm self-learning PHP - I know very few 'best practices' and would like to learn more.

Comment: What do you mean by "run in one page"? Do you want one function that dynamically runs the action and updates the corresponding table instead of a function for each action?

Comment: Hi Anthony, by 'run in one page' I mean that I would like to remove the clutter of having lots of extra PHP files that only have have a single purpose of running a single query. I'm wondering, if there is a way that all of these little 'action' PHP files could be merged into the main PHP file that displays the data.

Comment: That sounds very possible, without seeing the full code, but the fix sounds more like fixing the PHP logic and flow more than fixing mysql queries.  One big flag that the issue is not rooted in the db layer is that none of your code samples have database calls.

Comment: Hi Anthony, the SQL queries all work. All the code works - I am trying to update and simplify the code, and remove unnecessary code/files. So a different/better approach to my current working code, is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could consider is an MVC pattern, where a page call will run some function based on some parameters. A full-blown MVC framework is probably more than you need for this project, but mimicking the controller dispatching is certainly doable. Something to this effect could work (code untested):

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    new Actions()->dispatch('action_'.$_GET['action']);
}

class Actions {
    public function dispatch($action) {
        if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
            $this->$action($_GET);
        } else {
            http_response_code(400);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // The following functions are examples only!
    public function action_Create($parameters) {
        // Create database record
    }

    public function action_Read($parameters) {
        // Read database record
    }

    public function action_Update($parameters) {
        // Update database record
    }

    public function action_Delete($parameters) {
        // Delete database record
    }
}
```

Then you'd call (for example) `action.php?action=Read&name=foo&author=bar`

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your answer. This is quite interesting, as I recently used a similar concept for displaying errors. (e.g. error.php?permissions, for permission errors). I'm just wondering, if using your example you wanted to pass each action with a variable of `$name` and `$author` like your example link, how would you go about that?

Comment: [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) can do that, however it is unwise to blindly use `extract` on userdata like `$_GET`. You can supply a value to the `$flags` parameter of `extract` to make it more safe, for example `EXTR_SKIP` will not overwrite any of your existing variables and `EXTR_IF_EXISTS` would let you define exactly which keys to extract.

Comment: Something like this should work: `public function action_Create($parameters, $name = null, $author = null) { extract($parameters, EXTR_IF_EXISTS); /* etc... */ }`, and then only the `name` and `author` keys from `$_GET` would be turned into the variables `$name` and `$author`. (You'd also be able to check their values against `null` to see if they've been set at all.)